# Docker + Kafka: Is it possible to run a Consumer on Docker which reads from a Kafka topic outside Docker?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

we're trying to run a Consumer on Docker container and have Kafka, ZK and Schema Registry run outside Docker. Most of the examples I see for running Kafka inside Docker and making sure it is accessible from outside, are there any examples of the other way round i.e., making Kafka accessible inside Docker? Any leads/examples will help. Thank you!

Comment: Can you update the question with what you tried, please?

Answer (score 1):

A consumer inside a container should work the same as a consumer just on your host.

The broker's `advertised.listeners` should be the broker's external IP. When any client connects to this inside a container, it will be routed though the host's network interface.